# Перегрузка слота. qt

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Мне кажется что вопрос глупый, но всё же спрошу. Как правильно перегрузить QAbstractButton::clicked().Но я не уверен что мне это действительно нужно.

```
connect(addBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(MainWindow::addTimerBtn(timeEdit,textEdit)));
```

Я решил воспользоваться данной строчкой кода, чтобы привязать слот к сигналу. Но я так понимаю что сигнал должен быть тоже написан мной? Изначально я хотел сделать это не через connect, но просто через условие if. Будьте добры, подскажите как правильно

Comment: `connect(addBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, []() {} );` - лямбда, `connect(addBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &SomeClass::SomeFunction );` - функция из класса, [документация](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).  И это тоже будет [интересно](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что вы что-то не то пишите.

- Во-первых, `connect()` с макросами уже давно устарел. Он должен
  выглядеть как-то так:
  `connect(ptr2btn,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MyClass::mySlot);`
- Во-вторых, перегружать стандартный сигнал не за чем. Сигнал `clicked()`
  реализован **MOC**. Реализация зависит от платформы. Сигнал - не более
  чем прототип, у него не должно быть реализации.

PS: Вот так:

- Соединяете как обычно сигнал со слотом:
  `connect(ptr2btn,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MyClass::mySlot_1);`
- Определяете кастомный сигнал: `mySignal(Type_1,Type_2);`
- В `mySlot_1` вызываете `emit mySignal(param_1,param_2);`, который должен быть связан с `mySlot_2`.
- Или тоже самое лямбдой.

Обычно так не делается. Но я не знаю, какую цель вы преследуете, поэтому - что просили.

Comment: Да, я до этого так и писал, но мне бы хотелось передать 2 параметра в реализацию моего слота и я не знаю как правильнее это сделать.

Comment: @ДмитрийГуща, какие именно параметры? Конкретнее можно. `clicked()` передает `bool`, который можно опустить.

Comment: @ДмитрийГуща, вообще, если приспичило передавать что-то нестандартное с помощью стандартных сигналов, то сделайте так. Привяжите сигнал к лямбде (она как раз умеет делать захват), а внутри лямбды вызовите свой сигнал, и ему передайте параметры. Сигналы могут коннектиться с сигналами для транзитивной передачи, но поменять прототип таким образом не получится.

Comment: Возможно вы меня не правильно поняли, я имел ввиду два параметра именно в реализацию слота ` MainWindow::addTimerBtn(timeEdit,textEdit) ` эти параметры timeEdit и textEdit. Но, скорее всего я вас не понял.

Comment: @ДмитрийГуща, аргументы сигнала могут игнорироваться, а слота - нет. Поэтому так не получится. Переопределить не получится, но можно транзитивно передать кастомный сигнал через слот.

Comment: Похоже я вас понял, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: В слоте `mySlot_1` можно напрямую дернуть нужный метод без использования дополнительного сигнала